# Uploading Local Directory to GCS using Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, directory, upload, airflow

I am trying to use Airflow to Upload a Directory (with parquet files) to GCS.
I tried the [FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/file_to_gcs/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.file_to_gcs.FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator) for this purpose.

I tried the following options:

- **Option 1**

`src=<Path>/*.parquet`

it Errors out: `No such file found`

- **Option 2**

`src=<Path>` -> Where path is the directory path

it Errors out by saying that: `Is a directory`

**Questions**

1. Is there anyway, FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator can scale up to the directory level?
2. any alternate way of doing the same?

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer**: Currently it is not possible. But I will take it as a feature request and try to add this in the upcoming release.

Till then you can just use `BashOperator` and use `gsutil` to copy multiple files at the same time.

Another option is to use `PythonOperator`, list files using `os` package and loop over them and use the `GoogleCloudStorageHook.upload` to upload each file.